# Datable bootstrap does not work on dynamically table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble setting up the datable bootstrap. Here's the problem:

If the table is static, everything works fine, but if the table body is dynamically created based on the database information, the pagination and search function does not work. What should I do?

```
$('#tabela').dataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false
});
```

Table:

```
<table id='tabela' class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Produto</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Quantidade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tabelaProduto">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Dynamic table creation

```
function mostraTabela(produtos) {
    $('#tabelaProduto tr:first').remove();
    var prods = Object.keys(produtos);

    for (var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
        var produto = prods[i];
        var quantidade = produtos[produto];

        var $tr = $('<tr/>',{
        })
        var $prd = $('<td/>',{
            'text' : produto
        });
        var $qnt = $('<td/>',{
            'text' : quantidade
        });         
        $tr.append($prd).append($qnt).appendTo('#tabelaProduto').hide().fadeIn("slow");         
    }       
}
```

Comment: `but if the table body is dynamically created based on the database information` Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Done, @Webbanditten

Comment: If you call DataTables on the table before populating it, it may cause issues. Can you create a jsfiddle for this to show how order of the JavaScript?

Comment: @neologikadesenvolvimento take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pdzunf6y/

Comment: Also look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw() for after you make changes.